# Did illuminists explicitly say that science would set man free?

Tags: enlightenment

Is there any thinker/scientist who ever explicitly say that knowledge/science/technology would liberate man from need, bring universal well-being or paradise on earth?

(Note: H.G. Wells  said it about nuclear power in his book *The world set free*)

Comment: You can see [Science, Epistemology and Metaphysics in the Enlightenment](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/enlightenment/#TruSciEpiMetEnl) as well as [Auguste Comte](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/comte/#RelHum) for context; but IMO it is not easy to find it explicitly asserted.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, your links are not of help, but I found comte's "producers of dung" interesting, the more so , since when I google it to learn more, I got only a couple of hits, do you happen to know what it means?if you do I can ask a separate question